# Point group of trimethyl borate $\ce{B(OCH_3)3}$

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, stereochemistry, group-theory

What's the point group of trimethyl borate $\ce{B(OCH_3)3}$.
The answer that my teacher gave is $D_{3h}$ but I'm struggling to see the n perpendicular $C_2$ axes and the horizontal plane of reflection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's c3h without the perpendicular c2 axis.

Comment: You can see some other $C_{3h}$ molecules as this site https://molecule-viewer.com/  where there are also many examples and also of most other point groups. You can add axes and planes etc to help identify.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what conformation you're talking about. It can be $C_1$, $C_\mathrm{s}$, $C_3$, $C_\mathrm{3h}$, or $C_\mathrm{3v}$. This particular conformation that you provided the image, with $\ce{H-C-O-B}$ angle of $180^\circ$, the point group is $C_\mathrm{3h}$.

Answer (score -4):

The three C2 axes are along the three C-B bonds.
The horizontal plane of reflection is the plane defined by the boron and the three carbon atoms.

Comment: There are no C-B bonds here.